# merge two different array into one from one is dynamic & other is static

Tags: php, arrays

I want to merge three different arrays in a single array, from those, `$array2` is dynamic and the others are static. How would I get output from all merged arrays but with `$array2`'s multiple entries and other's single.

**I have 2 problems:**

1) If I closed `while` loop after `$arrary2` (before other array), I only get `$array2`'s last entry...not all

2) Mainly this: if I close the `while` loop after `$output['data'] = array($result);`, then the second entry will create a new array...but I want it in a single array. Any help would be appreciated.

**Here is part of my code:**

```
<?php
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {       

    $q2="select `image_kit_id` from `user_transaction` where `user_id`='$col'";

    $r2=mysql_query($q2);

    if($r2) {
        $count=0;
        while($ids=mysql_fetch_array($r2)) {
            $image_kit_id=$ids['image_kit_id'];
            //echo $image_kit_id;
            $q3="select * from `images` where `image_kit_id` = '$image_kit_id'";
            $r3=mysql_query($q3);
            $data=array();
            $i=0;

            while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($r3)) {
                $arr = array(
                             'imageid' => $row1['image_id'],

                             );
                $data[$i] = $arr;
                $i++;
            }
            $array2 = array($data);
            $count++;

            $array1 = array('user_id'=>$col);

            $array3 = array($data1);
            $array4 = array($data2);
            $array5 = array($data3);

            $result = array_merge($array1, $array2 ,$array3, $array4 ,$array5);

            $output['data'] = array($result);
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: I can't figure out what you're doing. Merging an associative array with indexed arrays usually doesn't make sense. Can't you just use `$result = $array1; array_push($result, $data, $data1, $data2, $data3)`?

Comment: Post an example of input data you have and output data you want to get.

Answer (score 1):

There is logic error in your code. I have corrected that according to my understanding, below. Tell me its working or otherwise what you want.

```
 $count=0; //here is no use of this, may be you need for counting
 $array2=array();

 while($ids=mysql_fetch_array($r2)) {
     $image_kit_id=$ids['image_kit_id'];

     $q3="select * from `images` where `image_kit_id` = '$image_kit_id'";
     $r3=mysql_query($q3);
     $data=array();

     while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($r3)) {
         $arr = array('imageid' => $row1['image_id']);
         $data[] = $arr;
     }
     $array2[] = $data;
     $count++;
 }
 $array1 = array('user_id'=>$col);
 $array3 = array($data1);
 $array4 = array($data2);
 $array5 = array($data3);
 $result = array_merge($array1, $array2 ,$array3, $array4 ,$array5);
 $output['data'] = array($result);
```

---

Also there are some logics are not clear, may be you need that type of `$output`, so just mentioning my points here:

1) You can directly store `$result` in `$ouput['data']=$result;`, coz `$result` is an array. why you are making is multidimensional by putting it in another array `array($result)`?

2) same logic in `$array2`, you can directly store `$row1['image_id']` in `$data[]`, coz in `$array2` you are **only storing** image ids, so you don't need associative array to tell that its `imageid`.

3) same thing is for all other arrays.

If your output format is not specific then I would suggest:

```
 $array2=array();
 while($ids=mysql_fetch_array($r2)) {
     $image_kit_id=$ids['image_kit_id'];

     $q3="select * from `images` where `image_kit_id` = '$image_kit_id'";
     $r3=mysql_query($q3);
     $data=array();

     while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($r3)) {
         $data[] = $row1['image_id'];
     }
     $array2[] = $data;
 }

 $output['data'] = array('user_id'=>$col, 'imageids'=>$array2, $data1, $data2, $data3);
   // first two element will have specified key(index), And last three's keys will be `0, 1 & 2` OR you can specify as you need OR remove the keys for first two also then keys will be `0, 1, 2, 3 & 4`.
 //OR remove the ['data'] also
 $ouput=array('user_id'=>$col, 'imageids'=>$array2, 'data1'=>$data1, 'data2'=>$data2, 'data3'=>$data3);
```

Comment: yup..ur right..but main problem is how to get multiple values of array2()...i want result like array(0)->id,array(1)->image_id(which is multiple according db),array(2)->data1,array(3)->data2,array(4)->data3....finaly i set output like this   $output['data'] = array('user_id'=>$col,$data,$data1,$data2,$data3);

Comment: @KetanJoshi My code will give you multiple value in `$array2`. array2 is a multidimensional array... `$array2($data[],$data[],$data[]....)`. You set output incorrectly. it should be `$output['data'] = array('user_id'=>$col,$array2,$data1,$data2,$data3);`. See my code second element is `$array2` not `$data`. $data will give you single and last values, that's why I put all datas in `$array2` then put it in output. **Remember $array2 is defined before first while loop**.

Comment: ohh.....yup...Thank you much for guided me......it's working..thanks a lot dear sir.......